# Ajax.Actionlink onsuccess script stop working after upgrading jquery to 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use to have jQuery version 1.8.2 & jquery-ui 1.8.24. and I have the following ajax.actionlink :-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Routers", "RackRouter","Rack", new {
id = Model.Rack.TMSRackID

}, new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "RackDetails"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress",
  OnSuccess="detailsuccess"
})
```

and the following function which is loaded inside a separate script file:-

```
function detailsuccess(data) {

        if (data.IsSuccess == "Unauthorized") {
            jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthorized Access');
        }
}
```

the above was working well. But i upgrade my jQuery from 1.8.2 to 1.9.1, and when i click on the above ajax.actionlink i am getting the following error using firebug:-

```
ReferenceError: detailsuccess is not defined jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js line 22 > Function:1
```

so why my ajax.actionlink can not find the detailsuccess script after upgrading it from version 1.8.2 to 1.9.1 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [release documentation](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) for 1.9.1 you will see the following

> The .live() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been
>   removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .on() method
>   instead.

The problem is your unobtrusive-ajax has live() events throughout it's code instead of on() events. You can get around this by downgrading your jQuery or upgrading your unobtrusive.ajax script.

I believe the updated version can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) in the form of a nuget package

Hope this helps

Comment: but if i use 1.8.2 my code will work well, as u mentioned that the .live has been deprecated since 1.7 ?

Comment: Yes it was depreciated in 1.7 but REMOVED in 1.9. So the live events no longer work with 1.9+. You could still use them in 1.8.